# Extract Checkbox or Multiple-choice Choices from a Google Form that Already Exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a Google Form that has not yet been published. I would like to extract all of the form's items, item types, and item choices (as applicable) for use in a mail merge. I can't use the Response spreadsheet, created by Google, because the form's users may not select all of the available choices for a given item.

My script functions adequately, except when trying to write the choices of a checkbox (or multiple-choice question or grid question) to the spreadsheet. When using the "getChoice" method, my spreadsheet shows an array of cells "={"Choice","Choice","Choice"}." It shows the word "Choice" over and over, instead of the actual choice that has been created on my form.

How can I write the actual choices to my spreadsheet, instead of the word "Choice" in an array? I am a javascript noob, so my apologies for any inelegant coding!

```
function extractForm() {
  var existingform = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/a/forms/d/fc/viewform');
  var items = existingform.getItems();
  var itemcount = existingform.getItems().length
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  

  for (var i = 1; i <= itemcount; ++i) {
  if (items[i].getType() != 'PAGE_BREAK' && items[i].getType() != 'SECTION_HEADER') {
    sheet.getRange(i,1).setValue(i);
    sheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(items[i].getTitle());
    sheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(items[i].getType());
    };
  if (items[i].getType() == 'CHECKBOX') {
    var chkItem = items[i].asCheckboxItem();
    var choicecount = chkItem.getChoices().length
    for (var j = 1; j <= choicecount; ++j) {
      sheet.getRange(i,4,1,j).setValue(chkItem.getChoices());
    };
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you simply get the array elements values like that ?

```
for (var j = 1; j <= choicecount; ++j) {
  sheet.getRange(i,4,1,j).setValue(chkItem.getChoices()[j].getValue());
};
```

Comment: @Serge_insas: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I knew that I had some type of array-dimension issue. And I had tried a lot of different parameters to specify the size of the array, but none had worked. And when I also tried to call getValue, I would receive a bizarre error.
  
The final code looks like this:
  
            sheet.getRange(i,4+j,1,1).setValue(chkItem.getChoices()[j].getValue());

Comment: Glad it helped... Please consider marking the question as answered.