# Google api - how do you get the text in Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

When i call `getContent()` on a Form file, it returns empty / null.

How do I get the textual content of a Form file in Google Drive?

Comment: i think to get the contents of a Form found from Google Drive you'd have to use the Forms service (which is a completely separate API than drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you need to use [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) to extract the contents of your Google Form.

**If you want to get the contents of the form (questions with choices), you need to use [`getItems()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getitems) method to get an array of all items in the form.**

```
// Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
 var form = FormApp.openById('Form_ID');

 // Logs the questions
var items = form.getItems()
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  Logger.log(items[i].getTitle());

// Logs the choices
  if (items[i].getType() == 'CHECKBOX') {
    var itemChoices = items[i].asCheckboxItem().getChoices()
    for (var j = 0; j < itemChoices.length; j++) {
    var choicesValue = itemChoices[j].getValue();
    Logger.log(choicesValue)
    }
  }
};
```

For [`getType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#getType()), you need to specify what type of choices the form has. In the sample code above, I used `asCheckboxItem()` to return checkbox items. Here are the [list of methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#methods) that you can use (`asCheckboxItem()`, `asMultipleChoiceItem()`, `asTextItem()`, etc.).

**If you want to get the contents of the form (questions with responses), you need to use [`FormResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) to get the responses to the form as a whole.**

```
// Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
 var form = FormApp.openById('Form_ID');

// Logs the questions with responses
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
   var formResponse = formResponses[i];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
         (i + 1).toString(),
         itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
         itemResponse.getResponse());
   }
 }
```

You may also refer with these SO threads:

- [Extract Checkbox or Multiple-choice Choices from a Google Form that Already Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127393/extract-checkbox-or-multiple-choice-choices-from-a-google-form-that-already-exis)
- [How to extract response items from a Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253706/how-to-extract-response-items-from-a-google-form)

Hope this helps!