# Implementing Google sheet API in html

Tags: html, forms, google-sheets-api

I am planning to use Google sheet API v4 in my website .
I have custom form, I want the data of form to dumbed in Google sheet 
I don't have any servers like Python, Apache, etc., in my host server

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122291/google-api-how-do-you-get-the-text-in-forms/42132178#42132178) on how to get the data in forms using [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/). Also check on this [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) on how to modify the spreadsheet using apps script. Then you can publish the script as a web app if the function returns an [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) [`HtmlOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) object or a [ontent service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) [`TextOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) object.

Here are the following tutorials which might help:

- [Saving Form Data to Google Spreadsheets Using PHP and the Google Docs API](http://www.farinspace.com/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/)
- [Google Sheets as a Database – INSERT with Apps Script using POST/GET methods (with ajax example)](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/)